# How to make * be treated as a literal in REGEX_LIKE in Oracle DB?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, literals

There's an Oracle database with a bunch of entries where there are '*' before, in the middle, and at the end of the string. I'm performing some data analysis and want to see how many entries that exist that have * somewhere in the middle of the string with at least one char before and after. However according to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm
* is a metacharacter, but I'm not sure how to make it be treated as a literal despite looking the the documentation. I've tried `[*], (*), \*`, but all have resulted in `ORA-00920: invalid relational operator`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable mT WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (mT.myCol, '.[*].');
```

Comment: `invalid relational operator` doesn't sound like a regex error.

Comment: @Jerry `.\\*.` also fails

Comment: Well, you know, the whole idea is to debug first, get the result last. I read it uses POSIX standards, the `*` as metachar and literal should be valid. Try to get anything working, use `'a[abcde]'` and verify the output. If the output is not as expected, then I think either your select or target is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work fine for me:

```
> drop table tabx
table TABX dropped.
> create table tabx
(
val varchar2(10)
)
table TABX created.
> insert into tabx values ('AB*CD')
1 rows inserted.
> insert into tabx values ('A*B')
1 rows inserted.
> insert into tabx values ('DEF')
1 rows inserted.
> commit
committed.
> SELECT * FROM tabx x WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (x.val, '.[*].')
VAL      
----------
AB*CD      
A*B
```

Your error may be coming from elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah I tried it on one of our serves with a new env, and it worked just fine. Also tried it on SQL Fiddle
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2f51e/2
Looks like it's due to the environment since it works on one of our servers running Enterprise 11.2.0.2, but not the one running 9.2.0.5. Marking as answer since this 'proof' is what caused me to consider it was the environment rather than my previous lack of SQL REGEXP experience

Comment: Regular expressions were introduced in version 10 @KurtWagner; your syntax errors are nothing to do with your syntax being incorrect; the version you're using just doesn't support the function.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to format the query is as follows:

```
REGEXP_LIKE(mT.myCol, '.*\*.*')
```

But I also don't think that the issue is with the regex.

Comment: I think this matches `*` alone, where he wants to match a character on both sides of it. And the `[*]` was an attempt to exclude quoting `\*` as a problem (which it isin't).